# Proof about infinite sum of fractions

Tags: real-numbers

```
 STATEMENT:
```

$t \in R$,  $0 < t < 1$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty t^i = \frac{t}{1-t}$$

```
 EXAMPLE:
```

let
   t = $\frac{1}{2}$

then,

## $\frac{1}{2}$ + $\frac{1}{4}$ + $\frac{1}{8}$  + ... = 1

let n=$\frac{2}{3}$

then,

$\frac{2}{3}$ + $\frac{4}{9}$ + $\frac{8}{27}$ + ... = 3

ex.1    $\frac{1}{2}$ + $\frac{1}{4}$ + $\frac{1}{8}$ + ...=1

ex.2   $\frac{9}{10}$ + $\frac{9}{100}$ + $\frac{9}{1000}$ + ...=1

```
 PROOF:
```

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty t^i = (1-t) + t(1-t) + t^2(1-t) + t^3(1-t) ... = 1, \; \; (t \in R, 0 < t < 1)$$

$$ = 1 + t + t^2 + t^3 + ... = \frac{1}{1-t} $$

$$ = t + t^2 + t^3 + ... = \frac{t}{1-t} $$

$$ = \sum_{i=1}^\infty t^i = \frac{t}{1-t}$$

---

I found this by myself and I think this is true. I wonder if I can apply it to something. If you know something about this topic, please let me know. I'm not very good at math and I might be wrong, so please forgive and help me.

Comment: You seem to have mixed $n$ and $t$.  These are examples of [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: As you are dealing with dots indicating infinity this is perhaps not an absolutely rigorous proof, but the idea is correct. You have actually just derived a well known sum for certain geometric series as expanded [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Answer (score 2):

This is well known to be a [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html). It is very useful in analysis.

Also, the series converge for $|t| < 1$, so $t$ can be negative.

Here is a somewhat more rigorous proof: The partial sums are given by
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} t_j = \frac{1-t^m}{1-t}
$$
so if $|t| < 1$,
$$ \lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{j=0}^{m-1} t_j = \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{1}{1-t} - \frac{t^m}{1-t} = \frac{1}{1-t}
$$
Since $\frac{t^m}{1-t} \to 0$.